# ¿Como puedo obtener unicamente los datos negativos de una columna en especifico en SQL?

Tags: sql

Ya que los datos, al realizar diferentes querys me arrojan errores.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Como indica el mensaje de cierre, puedes editar la pregunta para ajustarla a las normas del sitio y así será reabierta para que te respondan.

Answer (score 0):

La manera mas simple de hacerlo es utilizando una cláusula `where` sobre la columna que quiere filtrar y asegurarte que los numeros sean menores que 0. Aqui un ejemplo:

```
select * from tabla_ejemplo where columna < 0;
```